# Is there anything called Shallow Learning?

Tags: neural-networks

[IBM says that](https://www.ibm.com/topics/deep-learning):

> ***Deep learning*** is a subset of machine learning, which is essentially a neural network with three or more layers.

Therefore, the question is, is there anything called ***Shallow Learning*** that uses less than three layers of an artificial neural network?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the opposite of "deep learning" would be "shallow forgetting."

Comment: @whuber there is a formula for that ;o) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, for instance multi-layer perceptron (MLP) neural networks (with two layers of modifiable weights), support vector machines, Radial Basis Function (RBF) neural networks, Kernel Logistic Regression, Gaussian Processes.  There are a lot of "shallow" learning methods, and they are still very useful even if not very fashionable at the moment.  Linear regression and standard logistic regression are also "shallow learning".

Oddly enough, shallow learning methods can out-perform deep learning methods in some applications, but I suspect publication bias means that this isn't as widely appreciated as it should be.

Comment: Could you supply me a citation in favor of your answer?

Comment: It's probably better to use Google Scholar to find a paper that exactly fits your needs, e.g. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=shallow+learning&btnG= I don't think "shallow learning" is used as a term very often as it is essentially the default and people insert the "deep" bit to try and differentiate what they are doing.  However it often isn't a very useful distinction, I was using "deep learning" by the IBM definition back in the early 90s (we all were!), but it was just fairly standard neural network practice.

Comment: "Oddly enough, shallow learning methods often out-perform deep learning methods" is a claim that could benefit from supporting evidence, such as a citation to a comparative study.

Comment: @Sycorax "can" might be a better term for "often".  Citation for a comparative study might be difficult due to publication bias, and a lot of it depends on what kind of dataset you are looking at, DNNs don't work to well on some "standard" small-medium benchmark datasets, but great for images etc.  I saw a paper recently that used DNNs for a particular application I looked at 20 years ago using logistic regression.  LR works better, but never published it because LR wasn't interesting 20 years ago, and it certainly isn't now.

Comment: One of the difficulties with systematic studies is operator bias, it needs collaboration between DL and SL experts for a fair comparison.  An analysis of results from machine learning challenges would be interesting as at least there everybody is trying to win and most will be proficient with the models they use.

Comment: "I saw a paper recently that used DNNs for a particular application I looked at 20 years ago using logistic regression. LR works better..." I think you might actually be able to get some purchase with the journal that published that paper from a replication standpoint: if you can get the data & demonstrate that LR is better, then you've essentially got a counterintuitive result from an ablation study of the original paper.

Comment: @Sycorax, I have obtained the same data they used (they generally did a very commendable job of making the work replicable) and it is better in terms of accuracy, but not so much in terms of F1 (although it is not clear to me why that is a good metric).  One of the problems is that it is a commercial journal and I have no way of finding the publication fees, so I may just make it available on ArXiv (or however you spell it).

Comment: @downvoter some feedback on what is wrong with the answer would be appreciated, it seems pretty uncontroversial to me!

Answer (score 1):

"Machine learning" is the very general term used when you have an algorithm A that depends on a lot of parameters, and a second algorithm B that acts on A to automatically find the best parameters.

Neural networks are a subset of machine learning. The neural network itself is algorithm A; and most of the time, algorithm B is gradient descent.

Deep learning is a subset of neural networks refering to the particular case where the neural network has more than a few layers.

I'm not aware of a term for "non-neural network machine learning". However, the term "shallow learning" is indeed used when people want to explicitly contrast neural networks with few layers against neural networks with more layers.

Long story short, training a neural network with few layers but many neurons per layer requires more computational power than training a neural network with many layers and fewer neurons per layer. So for a long time, neural networks with many layers were avoided.

When computational power increased and it became reasonable to train deeper neural networks, this new "unlocked subfield" of machine learning was called "deep learning", and everyone working with deeper networks was very keen to put emphasis on the depth of their networks.

Comment: The first paragraph is incorrect.  Statistical models (e.g. ridge regression) can also have hyper-parameters that need to be tuned (e.g. via cross-validation), so that is not distinctive to ML.

Comment: Also the reason that deep neural networks were not used that often back in the day was not computational expense, but the gradient information becoming to diffuse to usefully train the lowest layers effectively.  The main different between then and now though is indeed computational, however IMHO it is more that it allows you to work with very large datasets rather than anything to do with the network architecture.  Very large datasets are often needed to get good results with the kinds of DL most people are interested in at the moment.